# how to do copy data from mysql table to .txt file and return back to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
select * from member into outfile 'c:/mysql/member.txt';
```

It is not returning varchar data into the text file.
Can I rewrite the data from .txt to mysql table?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean that it's not returning varchar data into the text file. Here is what I recommend:

1. Explicitly list the columns that you want to export
2. Explicitly define the termination of fields
3. Explicitly define the termination of lines

Example:

```
SELECT id, field_a, field_b...
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM table
```

You will have to adjust the columns according to the table you have and the output of where you want the file to go etc...